# How to convert a list of 2-tuples into dictionary keys in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of 2-tuples (being used as polygon coordinates). I'd like to convert this list to a dictionary but I'd like each tuple to be a key itself, rather than the first coordinate being a key and the second a value. How can I do this? It seems all the normal methods of converting lists to dictionaries take tuples to both keys and values.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. If the 2-tuple is the key, then what do you want the value to be?

Comment: You can use a tuple as a key just fine. What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to use as a value? This should work, anyway:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), ...]
d = {key: some_value for key in a}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! Actually I just wanted the values to start as None. I'm trying to write a function that will give a value to each of those coordinates. Thanks again!